# Questions about GMT iran?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, time, timezone

GMT iran-tehran is `+3:30` but why this site: http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/asia/iran/tehran/ putting GMT for iran-tehran `+4:30`?

How to change the GMT in iran? how set yourself clock with change GMT in iran?
**MY CODE:** http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/1/

Comment: How to change the GMT in iran? how set yourself clock with change GMT in iran? http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/1/

Answer (score 7):

Probably because of DST, it's not the same for every country.

Comment: How to change the GMT in iran? how set yourself clock with change GMT in iran? http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/1/

Answer (score 2):

A simple wrong 
beacuse they show Tehran gmt with Afghanistan (kabul) some times they show Kabul Time with Tehran 3:30 like Microsoft windows.

Answer (score 0):

We (Iranians) in Iran in the first of each year of `Shamsi Date` move our clocks forward 1 hour Simultaneously [ it means `+04:30` ] and on the first day of autumn, we return to the previous state [ it means `+03:30` ].

In short, this is to make the most of sunlight.

months 1-6  :  `+04:30`

months 6-12 :  `+03:30`